# How do I get rid of a header background on blogger and center my tabs?

Tags: html, tabs, header, background-image, blogger

My blog is: http://icantaffordmylifestyle.blogspot.com/ I'm trying to center my tabs and get rid of this awful header background.  It looks almost like crumpled paper in the background and I don't know how to get rid of it, it is behind my header and my tabs bar.  How can I get rid of it and center the tabs.  I tried added  tags but they don't work in in the html or the CSS.  Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the paper background image:

In this section of your code for that page:

```
.content-inner {
background: #ffffff url(//www.blogblog.com/1kt/travel/bg_container.png) repeat-x scroll top left;
background-position: left -5px;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Remove:

```
background: #ffffff url(//www.blogblog.com/1kt/travel/bg_container.png) repeat-x scroll top left;
```

To center the nav menu, edit this section:

```
#mbtnavbar {
/* background: #ffffff; */
width: 100%;
color: #3cd0b6;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
border-top:0px solid #ffffff;
height: 40px;
vertical-align: text-middle;
}
```

Change the width to 85%

Comment: Thanks so much! But I couldn't find that in my code.  Found this section starting on line 777:  <div class='content'> I can not find that background anywhere to delete.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this div in your content as so:  <div class="content-inner" style="background:none;">
as well as:  <div id="mbtnavbar" style="width:85%">

Comment: Thanks so much! So helpful.  Finally got rid of that background.  But I still can't get it centered.  I can't find the <div id=....) anywhere.  Should I be adding that in? If so where? I tried ass the other one to CSS, but it didn't work.

Comment: It looks like you modified the % in the css for the nav.  If you can do that, try changing it now to 95%.

/*----- MBT Drop Down Menu ----*/
<center>
#mbtnavbar {
/* background: #ffffff; */
width: 95%;